# 3 different sql queries in one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am aggregating 2 different values and want to calculate their differences and display it on the row

Example pseudo-code:

```
(SELECT SUM(column1) from database1.table1 where condition1) - (SELECT SUM(column2) from database2.table2 where condition2)=3rd Row
```

The Table should look like this

```
COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 | COLUMN1-COLUMN2
```

Can we do this in SQL ? Is it doable ?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output. Are dataset correlated somehow or you just need one row resultset? And yes it is doable in both cases :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
select a.asum,b.bsum,(a.asum-b.bsum) from 
       (select SUM(column1) as asum from database1.table1 where condition1)a,
       (SELECT SUM(column2) as bsum from database2.table2 where condition2)b
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be several different ways to do this depending on how you join to each table. I would probably do something like this.

```
select
sum(a.col) as value1
,sum(b.col) as value2
,value1-value2 as value3
from table a 
join table b   -- may need to be a left join? 
on a.something=b.something 
where a.something = 
and b.something =
```